# RSelenium vs. TikTok

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I want to scrape the information from the table [here](https://ads.tiktok.com/business/creativecenter/inspiration/popular/music/pc/en), which only shows 3 entries by default.

The following expands the table using the JS browser console:

```
document.querySelector(".view-more-btn--VGYaj").click();
```

But the equivalent does not work in `RSelenium`:

```
remDr <- RSelenium::remoteDriver(port = 4445L)
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)

js_script <- 'document.querySelector(".view-more-btn--VGYaj").click();'

remDr$executeScript(js_script, args = list("dummy"))
```

Why not?

Making the window full size or scrolling to the bottom before running `executeScript` does not help either:

```
# max window
remDr$maxWindowSize()

# scroll down
webElem <- remDr$findElement("css", "body")
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "end"))
```

`maxWindowSize()` and `sendKeysToElement()`  do work in and of themselves, however, when I watch how `RSelenium` affects the browser, the results are as expected. So it is something about the click command specifically that does not work.

Comment: Perhaps the click event handler isn't attached right away. What if you Add `Sys.sleep(2)` before running the javascript to give the page time to load.

Comment: Forgot to say, already tried that. Doesn't help :(

Comment: Are you emulating a mobile device? In that case you might need to dispatch a touch event instead.